# Сохранить результаты тестов в SQLite или SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Я новичок в Java и в Android. Пишу первое приложение, это тесты ПДД. Думаю делать где-то 40 билетов. Задача стоит в том что бы сделать грамотно статистику ответов. Я не знаю как это сделать. В приложение стандартно: Вопрос (textView) и 3 кнопки (Button). Я так понимаю на каждую кнопу нужно вешать какое-то значение. Например если брать SQLite это прописывать лучше int? Создать таблицу например "Билет1" и там данные типа int?и так по каждому билету? Если ответ не правильный это 0, если правильный 1. Но как их потом достать из БД? Нужно когда тест закончился вылезла активность с количеством правильных и не правильных ответов. Так же будет еще одна активность где нужно выбрать номер билеты и вылезет статистика ошибок. Есть ли какие-то уроки именно по таким тестам? Или мб вы мне логику объясните плиз. я пока не очень соображаю как это все лучше сохранить и как лучше читать из БД. Надеюсь вы меня поняли. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Зачем вам хранить их где то? И на какой срок? Для того что вы описали достаточно просто в переменную загнать кол-во правильных ответов, можно даже в мапу для большего функционала) расширьте пожалуйста ваш вопрос!

Comment: Хранить, что бы потом можно было смотреть результаты по билетам

Comment: Тогда база данных создаётся таблица тикет и статистика по каждому тикету пишется туда тикет-статистика. К стати где сами билеты то хранятся?

Comment: У меня tablayout,  viewpager,  и viewpageradapter который сэтит фрагменты на каджый item tablayout'а.  Вопросы думал сделать фрагментами. Я так понимаю есть вариант попроще чрез БД сделать?

Comment: Можешь использовать и SQLite. 1 таблица - Вопросы, 2 таблица - варианты ответов, 3 - статистика по ответам. Как подключаться к SQLite достаточно много примеров.

Comment: дополнил ответ по структуре с учетом вашего последнего вопроса (несколько билетов, в каждом из которых несколько вопросов), так же обратите особое внимание на то, что написано после метки **upd**

Comment: спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` никаким образом не подходит для использования в качестве хранилища подобного рода данных, однозначно необходимо использовать БД.

Вам нужно создать в БД таблицы *questions*, *answers*, *results* и *tickets* : в 1-ой -
 вопросы, во 2-ой - варианты ответов, с отметкой правильного, в 3-ей - прогресс, в четвертой - билеты.

В  *tickets* пишутся билеты и их ID:

```
| _id | ticket.   |
-------------------
| 1   | билет1  |
| 2   | билет2  |
```

В *questions* пишется ID вопросов, ID билета, к которому относится вопрос и собственно сами вопросы (текст):

```
| _id | question | id_ticket
----------------------------
| 1   | вопрос1  | 1
| 2   | вопрос2  | 1
| 3   | вопрос3  | 2
| 4   | вопрос4  | 2
```

Вопросы 1 и 2 относятся к первому билету, 3 и 4 - ко второму.

При выводе на экран вы получаете очередной билет из БД и выводите его вопросы. Делаете выборку из этой таблицы с условием `id_ticket = <номер билета>`, в результате вы получите все вопросы, относящиеся к нужному билету. ID (_id) вопросов сохраняете для последующего использования.

В *answers* пишутся ответы по следующей структуре:

```
| _id | ID_question | answer  | correct |
----------------------------------------
|  1  |  1          | ответ1.1|   0     |
|  2  |  1          | ответ2.1|   1     |
|  3  |  2          | ответ1.2|   1     |
|  4  |  2          | ответ2.2|   0     |
|  5  |  2          | ответ3.2|   0     |
```

первый столбец - собственный ID ответа, второй - ID вопроса, к которому относится этот ответ (здесь ответы с ID = 1 и 2 - к первому вопросу. 3, 4 и 5 - ко второму), третий столбец - сам ответ (текст), четвертый - отметка правильного ответа (1 - правильный ответ, 0 - неправильный).
Такая архитектура позволит включать к каждому вопросу произвольное количество ответов, например к первому - два варианта, ко второму - три варианта.

При выводе вариантов ответов делаете в БД запрос из таблицы *answers* по столбцу *ID_question* с ID равным ID вопроса, полученный ранее (при выводе вопроса). Когда пользователь выберет один из вариантов ответа, получаете значение *correct* для этого ответа и его содержимое пишите в таблицу *results* (столбец *result*), в столбец *ID_question* таблицы *results* пишем ID вопроса (полученный в начале)

В *results* пишем результаты прохождения тестов :

```
| _id | ID_question | result |
------------------------------
| 1   |  1          |        |
| 2   |  2          |        |
```

Столбец *result* заполняется по мере прохождения теста. В дальнейшем, простой выборкой столбца *result* по значению = 1 из этой таблицы вы получите и количество правильных ответов и ID тех вопросов, что отвечены правильно.

**upd** Имя автоинкрементируемого столбца с уникальным идентификатором для каждой таблицы (ID) в андроид должен называться именно *_id* (не id, Id, ID, id_2 и тому подобное), если вы планируете пользоваться стандартными классами андроид для работы с SQLite, в частности  `Cursor`, иначе будут проблемы, например, с итерацией того же курсора по записям. Так же этот столбец обязательно должен быть включен в выборку курсора.

Если у вас проблемы с организацией архитектуры БД и работы с ней, советую почитать книгу Бейли Л. - "Изучаем SQL (Бестселлеры O'Reilly)" - 2012г. в ней вы получите всю необходимую информацию

Очень подробно разбирается создание игры-викторины (по сути билеты ПДД та же викторина) в книгах, которые вам стоит почитать: П.Дейтел "Android для разработчиков" 2016г. и Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 2016г. второе издание.