# Викторина для андроид

Tags: android

В книге "Андроид для разработчиков" описан процесс создания игры викторина для угадывания флага страны. Подскажите пожалуйста, я хочу сделать нечто подобное, но без картинок просто вопрос и 4 варианта ответа. Где обычно хранят в таком случае вопросы и ответы? в БД, файле, в коллекции?

Comment: по возможной [структуре БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345) - несколько билетов, в каждом несколько вопросов, на каждый несколько ответов с запоминанием отвеченного (экзамен ПДД)

Comment: Спасибо. Стало понятно как организовать структуру БД.