# Приложение "Тесты" андроид

Tags: java, android

Есть `LinkedHashMap`, где ключ - это вопрос, а значение `TreeMap`, в котором ключи - это ответы, а значение `bool`(`true` ответ верный, `false` нет)

Дело в том, что количество ответов всегда разное. Не могу понять как реализовать создание кнопок под ответы.

Comment: Навскидку советую заменить Map с ответами на List, переместив признак верного ответа в сам текст ответа (* первым символом или еще как). Тогда будет проще проходить этот список и связывать кнопки с ответами по индексу.

Comment: Рекомендую [использовать базу данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345), как наиболее подходящий инструмент для решения такого рода задач. В конце рекомендации по книге с подробным разбором приложения типа тестов. Использование всевозможных коллекций для хранения данных с моей точки зрения вообще детский сад, который можно встретить только в учебных примерах, в основном.

Comment: Вместо кнопок в такого рода тестах (разное количество ответов) уместнее использовать список с RadioGroup, то есть в столбик список ответов и можно отметить правильный галочкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые вью (в том чилсе и кнопки) можно создавать динамически и добавлять на экран программно.
В вашем случае в xml можно определить контейнер для ответов (например вертикальный `LinearLayout`) и добавлять необходимое количество кнопок программно:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

for (i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
    Button btn = new Button(context);
    btn.setText(answers.get(i).text);
    btn.setTag(i);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    container.addView(btn);
}
```

Обработчик нажатий на кнопки будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch ((int) v.getTag()) {
            case 0:
                // Выбран первый ответ
                break;

            case 1:
                // Выбран второй ответ
                break;

            ...
        }
    }
};
```

Этот способ может оказаться проще, чем использование `List/RecyclerView` за ненадобностью написания адаптеров. А, так как количество ответов обычно небольшое (3-5), то и преимущество переиспользования вью в этих списках не будет задействовано.

Answer (score 1):

Советую реализовать `ListView` для таких целей. Всё, что касается неопределённого количества элементов (`ToDoList` и так далее) реализуется с помощью `RecyclerView` или `ListView` или подобных. Дело в том, что каждый такой список можно реализовывать в разном виде (это может быть меню, набор кнопок, галереи) и в него помещается не константное количество элементов. Если ответов в дереве немного - берите `ListView` по причине простоты. Для `RecyclerView` больше подойдёт задача в виде сообщений, галерей и так далее, где много элементов.