# Передача данных между активностями

Tags: android, activity

Делаю простенький тест на 3 вопроса, не понимаю, как в 4 активности с результатами отобразить данные, полученные из первых 3? Думал передавать данные из каждой активности в следующую. Или как передавать данные сразу в последнюю активность?

Comment: В книгах [у П.Дейтела](https://habrahabr.ru/company/piter/blog/303208/) и у [Б.Филлипса](https://habrahabr.ru/company/piter/blog/335146/) подробно разбирается создание приложений-викторины (тестов), лучше всего вам почитать эти книги. Для начала вам не нужно три активности для трех вопросов - нужна одна, в которой меняется содержимое. Во вторых такие данные не передаются между контроллерами, а хранятся в постоянном хранилище, к которому может обратиться любой контроллер для чтения или изменения.

Comment: Можете почитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345) о организации хранилища для тестов на основе БД, для трех вопросов это несколько сложное решение, но сама суть должна быть вам понятна - как получать, как отмечать верные, откуда забирать результат.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)