# Как лучше хранить вопросы и ответы у викторины в андроид?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Делаю викторину для андроида.
Один вопрос, изображение к вопросу и 8 вариантов ответа.
Как лучше хранить вопросы и ответы? Я понимаю, что лучше в SQL, но вот как создать такую базу в приложении ума не приложу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345

Comment: Забавно, именно такой пример разбирается в начале [этого учебника](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/144943814/).

Answer (score 0):

В android используется база данных SQLite

Почитайте поподробнее про БД.

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html

Answer (score -1):

Не обязательно использовать SQL. Рекомендую присмотреться к Realm https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/.
У Realm есть свои плюсы и минусы, но вашу задачу она решит быстро и эффективно.
Вот несколько примеров кода:

Пример модели данных:

```
public class Question extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String question;
    private String answer

}
```

Получение экземпляра realm:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
```

Сохранение в Realm:

```
Question question = new Question();
Realm realm = Realm.insertOrUpdate(question)
```

Получение экземпляров вашей модели данных:

```
RealmResults<Question> tempSendModels = realm.where(Question.class)
                                             .equalTo("question", "question content")
                                             .findAll();
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ. Возьмите за пример [этот ответ в связанной теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345). Ваше сообщение пока не отвечает на вопрос ТС.

Comment: для структуры типа вопрос - ответы более подходит реляционная база, чем объектная