# SQLite. Создание множества однотипных таблиц c разными именами

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Имеется приложение которое хранит свои данные в БД. Все таблицы Отличаются только именем и данными. Проблема : каждое создание таблицы происходит вот так,

```
String SQL_CREATE_GUESTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Columns.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + Columns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + Columns.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, "
            + Columns.COLUMN_ANSWERS + " TEXT, "
            + Columns.COLUMN_CORRECT + " INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_GUESTS_TABLE);
```

Columns - внутренний класс-контракт

```
public static final class Columns implements BaseColumns {
    public static String TABLE_NAME = // ЕСЛИ ВСТАВЛЯТЬ СЮДА КОНКРЕТНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, ТО ПРОБЛЕМ ПРИ РАБОТЕ НЕ ВОЗНИКАЕТ,
    public static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;      //   НО КАЖДАЯ ТАБЛИЦА ДОЛЖНА ИМЕТЬ СВОЕ ИМЯ
    public static String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
    public static String COLUMN_ANSWERS = "answers";
    public static String COLUMN_CORRECT = "correct";
}
```

Если я пытаюсь инициализировать TABLE_NAME переменной которая приходит из конструктора внешнего класса, то вылетает ошибка "near "quiz": syntax error". Так как же мне инициализировать эту переменную под каждую таблицу?

Comment: Посмотри что значит final в имени класса Columns и все поймешь.

Comment: Структура базы должна создаваться ДО ее использования, а не генерироваться в процессе. Если во время работы с БД вам требуются новые таблицы, с большой долей вероятности вы неправильно проектировали структуру своей БД. Вот [пример правильной структуры БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345) с карточками вопрос-ответ. Такая структура позволяет легко расширять любые поля (добавлять вопросы, ответы и карточки) без изменения структуры БД и кода, ее обслуживающего, а также допускает произвольное количество ответов на разные вопросы (а не на все вопросы, например, три варианта ответа)

Comment: также, как нетрудно заметить, структура БД по ссылке включает всего 4 таблицы и остается неизменной  при любом количестве карточек, вопросов в них и ответов на вопросы, даже если их добавлять после создания БД. Это и есть правильная архитектура