# Как лучше использовать SQLite в своем приложении?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, scene-builder

Делаю приложение на JavaFX и Scene Builder

Приложение похоже на ТВ программу "Своя игра"

Имеется 8 категорий в главном окне.

При клике на категорию появляется карточка в центре экрана.Карточки будут вопросные и не вопросные(текстовые предложения). Если появляется вопросная карточка, то на карточке есть вопрос, а при клике на горячую клавишу(например "Пробел") карточка переворачивается(какая-нибудь анимация) и на карточке появляется ответ.

Вопросные карточки связаны с каждой категорией. Например: если пользователь кликает на категорию "Музыка", то появляется вопрос(если это вопросная карточка) :"Кто ваш любимый певец?", если пользователь жмет на пробел, карточка переворачивается и появляется ответ: "Doris Day" Если пользователь выбрал другую категорию, например "Машины", то появляется вопрос: "Кто был основателем компании Ford?" то при клике на горячую клавишу появляется ответ на карточки:"Henry Ford"

Всего будет примерно 100 карточек с вопросами на каждую категорию. ТО есть в сумме 800 карточек с вопросом и ответом, а карточки с простыми предложениями тоже будет около 100.  Вопросные карточки связаны с ответами. Не вопросные карточки ни связаны ни с чем.

Логика появления карточек на главном экране: 70% вопросных карточек, 30 % НЕ вопросных карточек. То есть получается мне нужно будет добавить какой рандом специальный для этого.

Также имеются кнопки.

Одна кнопка открывает меню редактирования вопросных карточек(new stage): пользователь может добавить новую карточку с вопросом и ответом в базу данных, удалить выбранную карточку, редактировать выбранную карточку. Также там есть label, который отображает букву английского алфавита. Буква создается рандомно на каждую карточку с ответом при запуске программы. Также есть в этом окне редактирования номер выбранной карточки. Если пользователь удалил карточку с текущим вопросом, то все номера в базе данных сдвигаются и к карточкам присваиваются новые номера. Номера карточек присваиваются автоматически при создании карточек. То есть сама база данных назначает номер на карточку
Label с номером вопроса нужен только в этом окне редактирования. Он отображает текущий номер в базе данных. При клике на него появляется список(combobox) всех номеров карточек из базы данных

Вторая кнопка для редактирования карточек с предложениями вызывает новое окно(stage) оно аналогично окну редактирования вопросных карточек, только там всего одно поле с textaria

Вся база данных карточек будет локальной и находится в папке с программой. Я думаю SQLite хорошо для этого подойдет. Я никогда не работал с базами данных и SQLite в том числе. Это будет моим первым опытом.

Также я хочу,чтобы файл с базой данных был связан с файлом EXCEL, который будет находится в этой же папке. Так как пользователь не знает как открыть и посмотреть файл базы данных, я решил использовать файл excel, excel есть на каждой машине и он прост в использовании. Нужно,чтобы файл базы данных и файл excel были связаны между собой. ТО есть если пользователь внес коррективы в базу данных из программы, то файл excel автоматически обновился.И наоборот: отредактировал excel - база данных автоматически обновилась

**Какой лучше подход использовать при работе с базой данных SQLite?**

**Сделать ли две таблицы: одна с вопросными карточками(номер вопроса,        ответ,      буква ответа) другая с карточками предложений( номер,        текст , предложения)?**

**Или всё запихать в одну таблицу? (номер вопросной карточки,         вопрос,        ответ,        номер НЕвопросной,   карточки,         текст предложения)**

Если будет две таблицы для разных карточек, то возможно ли будет сделать шанс выпадения из двух таблиц?: 70%/30%

**Есть ли у вас свои предложения по реализации моей задумки?**

*Дизайн всех fxml готов, осталось сделать логику добавления/удаления карточек в базе данных

Для более ясной картины прикладываю видео:

[Video](https://hdd.tomsk.ru/desk/ugjeoxjo#)

[image: Qeustion cards]

[image: Non Question Cards]

Comment: касаемо таблицы, судя из описания она одна: идентификатор; номер карточки (который нужно сдвигать , но непонятно зачем); тип карточки (вопросная/текстовая); текст карточки; ответ карточки (опционально),  связанная категория (но можно и без этого поля).
Наличие экселевской таблицы сильно переусложнит программу, придется при запуске анализировать всю базу, весь эксель, синхронизировать их и обрабатывать конфликты. SQLite достаточна прост и для текущих целей более чем сгодится.

Comment: По поводу сдвига номера карточки: если я к примеру выберу номер 35 и удалю его, то пустая строка из базы данных исчезает, а номер карточки,который был ниже его, то есть 36 становится выше и становится уже номером 35. Или как база данных SQLite работает?

Comment: о [организации базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345) в игре типа викторины

Comment: @pavloff Благодарю!