# Как использовать несколько связанных таблиц в базе данных Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Не понимаю как реализовать взаимодействие связанных таблиц в БД sqllite для Android. Для одной таблицы, к примеру, для метода add я просто добавлял всё в content values и insert это в бд, а тут как быть? Нужно ли вообще создавать классы производитель и вид продукта, или вся информация должна храниться в продукте? Был бы благодарен, если бы написали, к примеру, метод добавления нового продукта в такую БД, думаю дальше я пойму. Про ключи я знаю, а вот как их тут использовать - нет.
Про room и firebase, пожалуйста, не надо.
[image: База данных]

Comment: метод insert() в андроид возвращает id сделанной записи. делаете инсерт "продукт", сохраняете id, который вернул метод  и записываете (инсерт) в нужный "вид продукта" и далее по цепочке, а вобще в вопросе нет ни структуры таблиц, ни как организована связь, ни задач по использованию данных (какие планируются выборки и нужно ли вообще связывание)

Comment: ваш ответ я понял, спасибо. извиняюсь за плохие формулировки, просто и сам плохо понимаю/представляю структуру, мне по заданию нужно сделать)

Comment: может вы подскажете тогда как всё таки должно быть по логике. то что вы описали не сходится с тем как я это представляю. мне казалось, что основной элемент это продукт и он должен хранить информацию и о производителе и о виде. получается вот когда я создаю объект продукта и добавляю его в таблицу продукта, но в тоже время мне нужно его поля с производителем и видом добавить в другие таблицы. не знаю можно ли так, если да, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как?)

Comment: чтобы понять, зачем так делать, вам нужно много прочитать по дисциплине СУБД, в частности о связях один ко многим, многие ко многим и для чего их вообще используют, формат ответов этого ресурса не предполагает столь объемных теорий в ответе. при вашей структуре на рисунке, продукт и будет иметь информацию и о виде и о производителе за счет связи между ними, связывание же позволяет работать не только с продуктами (выбирать, сортировать, удалять, добавлять и тд), но и с их видами и производителями, как самостоятельными сущностями и как с любыми их комбинациями и всеми вместе

Comment: в таблицы видов и производителей вы добавляете не сами продукты, а некий их уникальный идентификатор, осуществляющий связь таблиц. по тем скудным сведениям, что содержатся в вашем вопросе трудно сказать что то более определенное, [смотрите, как пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345), структуру БД для викторины, может ответ поможет вам понять или хотя бы узнать, что нужно в вопросе для более определенного ответа вам. заодно и литературу в конце, особенно первая книга