# Хранение данных в Android-приложении

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Планирую создать Android-приложение. Знаю, что есть множество различных способов хранения информации. Какой вариант лучше всего подходит для моего случая?

Предположим, что мы занимаемся разработкой какого-нибудь приложения-викторины, которое будет содержать множество различных вопросов, а следовательно и много текстовой информации. Были мысли создать для этих целей БД, но не уверен в том, что это будет правильно. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать встроенную БД? Правда ее можно будет попробовать взломать, тогда все ответы будут узнаны. Есть вариант получать запросы с сервера, на котором находится какая-либо СУБД

Comment: @danilshik А если я буду хранить всю текстовую информацию в отдельном файле? Какие недостатки имеет данный способ хранения информации?

Comment: тот же, ответы может вытащить любой. Причем еще проще, достаточно только найти путь до файла

Comment: @danilshik Какой же способ более безопасный?

Comment: делать API запросы к серверу, где находится БД

Comment: @danilshik, безопасность от этого не повысится. Перехватить запрос к серверу - дело пары минут. Данные на клиенте защитить невозможно в принципе. По вопросу - используйте БД. В любом случае - будет у вас сервер или нет. С БД удобно. С файлами - намучаетесь, если будет в них что-то сложнее JSON в пару сотен строк.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы хотите сказать, чтобы он подключался напрямую к удаленной БД, без сервера? Например через jdbc?

Comment: Не важно как подключаться, если подключение есть, то любая программа перехвата трафика покажет полные тексты всех запросов в которых будет вся передаваемая информация. Её, конечно, можно зашифровать SSL сертификатом, но и это обходится его подменой и даже SSL пиннинг не поможет. Можно лишь усложнить задачу получения инфы, защититься от этого просто невозможно.

Comment: 1 встроенная бд - sqlite и ей подобные - realm etc, 2 как вариант  firebase , 3 написать свое api  и сделать серверную часть. Из плюсов firebase и серверной можно обновлять онлайн, добавлять вопросы итд.  Из плюсов sqlite полностью бесплатно и офлайн, встроенная. А так решать вам.

Comment: использовать БД будет правильно. Как [использовать БД для приложения типа викторина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345). Если вас волнет взлом, то данные можно шифровать

Comment: В суну свои пять копеек, как по мне обычную бд легко вскрыть через приложение скачанное из PlayMarket-a, но вот с Realm-mo другая история, сколько они не предлагают инструментов чтобы открыть посмотреть что там в базе творится, то не один не работает(: потому всё зависит от уровня требований.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да кому это надо взламывать андроид приложение викторины?
Вы слишком заботитесь о своем приложении, для такого пустяка достаточно хранить данные в самом приложении используя собственный формат файла, который использует тот же самый XOR текста. 
Ну или использовать что-то вроде хранения данных по типу Ключ - значение, где Ключ - это вопрос, а значение - ответ на вопрос.