# Помогите пожалуйста составить алгоритм выдачи ответов

Tags: java, android

- Есть 10 пар ответов на один и тот же вопрос .

  Нужно при нажатии на любой  вариант из пары ответов - менять всю пару ответов на следующую .

Я думаю нужно сделать :

- массив данных вопросов в [ string - array ]
- в коде получить к ним доступ через someArray[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name)
- Попробовать через циклы пройтись по ним
- Через setText назначать новую пару вопросов

  Как мне лучше сделать это ? (фото просто как пример пар ответов)
  [image: Фото как пример]

Comment: вопрос - ответ, какой алгоритм вы о чем ? 
У вопроса есть список ответов, один из них помечен как правильный - конец. Мб я что-то не понимаю, покажите что вы уже сделали

Comment: Из описания непонятно что там вопросы или ответы

Comment: Поправил описание вопроса , прошу прощения .

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345