# Quiz app для андроид

Tags: java, android, json

подскажите пожалуйста, я делаю приложение для тестирования уровня знаний в языке, знаю что тест должен быть в JSON формате, как правильно реализовать весь функционал, чтобы в фрагменте менялись данные, чтоб правильно отслеживать правильные ответы, какие тему изучить?

Comment: немного про [реализацию тестов ПДД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345), что по сути то же, что и ваша задача

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если кратко:

1. Создаёте структуру данных вида:

   ```
   [
     {
       "id" : 1,
       "question" : "How do something?",
       "answer" : "Do it so."
     },
     ...
   ]
   ```
2. Её сохраняйте в БД или даже просто файлом.
3. Считывайте в приложении в список объектов либой типа `GSON`, если просто из файла или уже средствами либы для БД типа `Room`
4. Одним из множества способов отслеживайте ввод юзера. Как только введённое совпадает с тем, что в поле `answer` - юзер угадал.

Comment: Подскажите а с помощью каких средств можно реализовать динамическую смену вопроса

Comment: @GeorgeGrigoryants, можно очень многими способами. Например, после успешного ответа юзера можно сменить объект в переменной, содержащей вопрос и переназначить все кнопки и содержимое текстовых полей для отображения нового вопроса. Или можно фрагмент заменить, передав ему ID следующего вопроса. Или ViewPager сделать и в нём фрагменты менять. Слишком общий вопрос, не знаю как ответить)

Comment: это все круто, но я не понимаю какие темы мне изучить для реализации, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: @GeorgeGrigoryants, сложно вам ответить. Не ясно что вы уже знаете и на каком уровне. Попробую пальцем в небо ткнуть: JSON, GSON, TextWatcher. Это поможет составить структуру данных, распарсить её и реагировать на ввод юзера в EditText.