# Отправить файл в активность из разметки

Tags: android, ресурсы

Есть справочник с несколькими разделами. Каждый раздел - это две активности, одна со списком пунктов, вторая - непосредственно "читалка" из txt на экран.
Но так как в справочнике много разделов (уже более 10), то, по сути, требуется очень много одинаковых активностей. Сама "читалка" так вообще почти полностью совпадает от раздела к разделу (разница только в указании xml с разметкой и самое главное с указанием имени файла txt (так как он "отправляется" из предыдущей активности, то это имя - переменная n0, n1....nX).
Хочу оптимизировать программу и заодно решить ряд дополнительных задач:
1. Сделать "читалку" одну на все разделы
2. Список формировать не активностью, а в разметке xml, но как "отправлять" ссылку на текстовый файл (лежит в ресурсах res/raw прямо из разметки?)
3. Реализовать поиск по списку пунктов (сейчас это невозможно, так как он формируется в активности, где каждая строчка привязана к имени n0, n1....nX)
 Как это реализовать программно?
Ниже привожу код активностей

Список:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class UP_rf extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Создаем массив разделов:
    private String head_array[] = {
            "00 О применении судами общей юрисдикции общепризнанных принципов и норм международного права и международных договоров Российской Федерации",
            "01 О практике применения судами положений части 6 статьи 15 Уголовного Кодекса Российской Федерации",
            "02 О применении судами законодательства о необходимой обороне и причинении вреда при задержании лица, совершившего преступление",
            "03 О практике назначения и изменения судами видов исправительных учреждений",
            "04 О практике назначения судами Российской Федерации уголовного наказания",
            "05 О применении судами законодательства, регламентирующего основания и порядок освобождения от уголовной ответственности",
            "06 О судебной практике условно-досрочного освобождения от отбывания наказания, замены неотбытой части наказания более мягким видом наказания",
            "07 О судебной практике применения законодательства, регламентирующего особенности уголовной ответственности и наказания несовершеннолетних",
            "08 О практике применения судами принудительных мер медицинского характера",
            "09 О некоторых вопросах, связанных с применением конфискации имущества",
            "010 О судебной практике по делам об убийстве (ст. 105 УК РФ)",
            "011 О судебной практике по делам о защите чести и достоинства граждан, а также деловой репутации граждан и юридических лиц",
            "012 О судебной практике по делам о преступлениях против половой неприкосновенности и половой свободы личности",
            "013 О некоторых вопросах судебной практики по делам о преступлениях против конституционных прав и свобод человека и гражданина (статьи 137, 138, 138.1, 139, 144.1, 145, 145.1 Уголовного Кодекса Российской Федерации)",
            "014 О судебной практике по уголовным делам о нарушениях требований охраны труда, правил безопасности при ведении строительных или иных работ либо требований промышленной безопасности опасных производственных объектов",
            "015 О практике рассмотрения судами уголовных дел о нарушении авторских, смежных, изобретательских и патентных прав, а также о незаконном использовании товарного знака",
            "016 О судебной практике по делам о краже, грабеже и разбое",
            "017 О судебной практике по делам о мошенничестве, присвоении и растрате",
            "018 О судебной практике по делам о вымогательстве (статья 163 Уголовного Кодекса Российской Федерации)",
            "019 О судебной практике по делам о преступлениях, связанных с нарушением правил дорожного движения и эксплуатации транспортных средств, а также с их неправомерным завладением без цели хищения",
            "020 О судебной практике по делам о нарушении правил пожарной безопасности, уничтожении или повреждении имущества путем поджога либо в результате неосторожного обращения с огнем",
            "021 О практике применения судами законодательства, регламентирующего особенности уголовной ответственности за преступления в сфере предпринимательской и иной экономической деятельности",
            "022 О судебной практике по делам о незаконном предпринимательстве",
            "023 О судебной практике по делам о легализации (отмывании) денежных средств или иного имущества, приобретенных преступным путем, и о приобретении или сбыте имущества, заведомо добытого преступным путем",
            "024 О судебной практике по делам об изготовлении или сбыте поддельных денег или ценных бумаг",
            "025 О практике применения судами уголовного законодательства об ответственности за налоговые преступления",
            "026 О некоторых вопросах судебной практики по уголовным делам о преступлениях террористической направленности",
            "027 О практике применения судами законодательства об ответственности за бандитизм",
            "028 О судебной практике рассмотрения уголовных дел об организации преступного сообщества (преступной организации) или участии в нем (ней)",
            "029 О судебной практике по делам о хищении, вымогательстве и незаконном обороте оружия, боеприпасов, взрывчатых веществ и взрывных устройств",
            "030 О судебной практике по делам о контрабанде",
            "031 О судебной практике по уголовным делам о хулиганстве и иных преступлениях, совершенных из хулиганских побуждений",
            "032 О судебной практике по делам о преступлениях, связанных с наркотическими средствами, психотропными, сильнодействующими и ядовитыми веществами",
            "033 О судебной практике по делам о преступлениях, предусмотренных статьей 238 Уголовного Кодекса Российской Федерации",
            "033 О применении судами законодательства об ответственности за нарушения в области охраны окружающей среды и природопользования",
            "034 О некоторых вопросах применения судами законодательства об уголовной ответственности в сфере рыболовства и сохранения водных биологических ресурсов (часть 2 статьи 253, статьи 256, 258.1 УК РФ)",
            "035 О судебной практике по уголовным делам о преступлениях экстремистской направленности",
            "036 О судебной практике по делам о злоупотреблении должностными полномочиями и о превышении должностных полномочий",
            "037 О судебной практике по делам о взяточничестве и об иных коррупционных преступлениях",
            "038 О судебной практике по делам о преступлениях, предусмотренных статьей 314.1 Уголовного Кодекса Российской Федерации",
            "039 О некоторых вопросах, возникающих при рассмотрении судами дел об административном надзоре за лицами, освобожденными из мест лишения свободы",
            "040 О практике рассмотрения судами уголовных дел об уклонении от призыва на военную службу и от прохождения военной или альтернативной гражданской службы",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.up_rf);

        // Получим идентификатор ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //устанавливаем массив в ListView
        listView.setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, head_array));
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        //Обрабатываем щелчки на элементах ListView:
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(UP_rf.this, Detail_UP_rf.class);

                intent.putExtra("head", position);

                //запускаем вторую активность
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

"читалка"

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Detail_UP_rf extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.detail__up_rf);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
        String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

        //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.erstendev.ppvsn"));

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
    }

    //читаем текст из raw-ресурсов
    public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

        InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: судя по коду, у вас всего две активности. почему вы пишите, что требуется **много** одинаковых? вообще вам нужна база данных, в которой будет структурирована вся ваша информация и доступ к конкретным записям через связи в этой базе (а не по пунктам списка). ваш вопрос слишком общий, чтобы писать полезный ответ, можете посмотреть, как [структурируется база с несколькими уровнями вложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345) (на примере карточек ПДД, только у вас будет:билеты -разделы, вопросы-пункты разделов, ответы-статьи пунктов). так же с использованием БД легко организовать поиск.

Comment: Таких пар, какие я привел выше, у меня несколько. Понятно, что можно реализовать на БД, просто хотелось бы на файлах ресурсов, без БД

Comment: на этих файлах ресурсов задача сильно усложняется, но вы пишете свою программу, вам и решать конечно. в частности организовать поиск с вашей текущей структурой данных видится задачей невыполнимой без разных костылей, как ассоциативные массивы. в общем случае вам требуется ещё одна активность с разделами, которая будет пересылать во вторую номер раздела, которая будет по номеру раздела выводить заголвки статей и пересылать в третью имя файла статьи, в общем то решение банальное

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть в сторону БД